# Why isn't my array kept in storage

Tags: contract-development, events, arrays

I'm a newbie at ethereum development (which I'm very enthusiastic about) and I'm trying very hard to create my first smart contract.

It's a test contract to bet on horses race.

I'm currently facing an issue that I failed to solve yet.

1) I can't find to way to log the `event` triggered to debug my code

2) When I initialize my `Race` struct, the `horsesRunningTheRace` doesn't seem to be properly set. It tried several ways but no success so far.

Here is my code so far (I simplified and translated it to focus at the issues):

My contract :

```
contract HorseRacesBet {

    struct Race {
        uint raceId;
        uint stakesSum;
        bool isOver;
        bool areBetsForbidden;
        uint32[] horsesRunningTheRace;
    }

    address public owner = msg.sender;

    uint courseIDGenerator = 0;
    mapping (uint => Race) races;

    modifier ownerOnly()
    {
        if (msg.sender != owner)
            throw;
        _
    }

    event InitRace(uint32[] horsesRunningTheRaceParam);

    function initRace(uint32[] horsesRunningTheRaceParam) ownerOnly returns(uint) {
        InitRace(horsesRunningTheRaceParam);
        races[courseIDGenerator].raceId= courseIDGenerator;
        races[courseIDGenerator].stakesSum=100;
        races[courseIDGenerator].isOver=false;
        races[courseIDGenerator].areBetsForbidden=false;
        for(uint x= 0; x< horsesRunningTheRaceParam.length; x++ ){
           races[courseIDGenerator].horsesRunningTheRace.push(horsesRunningTheRaceParam[x]);
        }
        courseIDGenerator++ ;
        return races[courseIDGenerator].raceId;
    }

    event GetRaceInfos(uint raceId);

    function getRaceInfos(uint raceIdParam) public returns(uint, uint, bool, uint32[], bool){
       GetRaceInfos(raceIdParam);
       return (races[raceIdParam].raceId, races[raceIdParam].stakesSum, races[raceIdParam].isOver, races[raceIdParam].horsesRunningTheRace , races[raceIdParam].areBetsForbidden);
    }
}
```

The Javascript Mocha test file :

```
contract('HorseRacesBet', function(accounts) {

    it("should keep a Race struct in the storage on initRace call", function() {
        var horseBetContract = HorseRacesBet.deployed();
        var horsesRunningTheRace = [10, 20, 30];

        horseBetContract.allEvents(function(error, result) {
            // This will catch all Transfer events, regardless of how they originated.
            console.log('event log');
            if (error == null) {
                console.log(result.args);
            }
        });

        horseBetContract.initRace.call(horsesRunningTheRace).then(function(raceId) {
            assert.equal(raceId.valueOf(), 0, "L'id de la course should be 0'");

            horseBetContract.getRaceInfos.call(raceId).then(function(raceDatas){
                assert.equal(raceDatas[0], 0, "The raceId returned should be 0");
                assert.equal(raceDatas[1].valueOf(), 0, "The sum of all bets should be 0.");
                assert.equal(raceDatas[2], false, "The race shouldn't be over");
                for(var i = 0 ; i< raceDatas[3].length; i++){
                    console.log(raceDatas[3][i].valueOf());
                }
                assert.equal(raceDatas[3], horsesRunningTheRace, "The horses running the race should be the one we initialized the race with.");
                assert.equal(raceDatas[4], false, "The bets shouldn't be closed on the race.");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And the output of the test:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/test.js:322
>   
>           throw reason;
>   
>           ^
>   
>     AssertionError: The horses running the race should be the one we initialized the race with.: expected [] to equal [ 10, 20, 30 ]
>   
>     at /Users/user/Documents/formation/nigthclazz-ethereum/truffle-project/horse-bet/test/horseRacesBet.js:24:16
>   
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)

Can anyone point me to what I'm obviously missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first point, I'm used to declare the *fromBlock* argument to retrieve all events from the genesis :

```
horseBetContract.allEvents({ fromBlock: 0 }, function(error, data) { 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Otherwise, according to the [Truffle official documentation](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/contracts/#executing-contract-functions), you could try to use **watch** (never tried)

```
horseBetContract.InitRace({fromBlock: "latest"}).watch(function(error, data) { 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

For the second point, I changed a couple of things in your test to make it work. You contract was fine.
Please find below the explanation :

```
horseBetContract.allEvents({ fromBlock: 0 }, function(error, result) {
        // This will catch all Transfer events, regardless of how they originated.
        console.log('event log');
        if (error == null) {
            console.log(result.args);
        }
});

horseBetContract.initRace(horsesRunningTheRace).then(function(transactionId) {
    console.log("transactionId="+transactionId);

    horseBetContract.getRaceInfos.call(0).then(function(raceDatas){

        assert.equal(raceDatas[0], 0, "The raceId returned should be 0");

        assert.equal(raceDatas[1].valueOf(), 100, "The sum of all bets should be 100.");

        assert.equal(raceDatas[2], false, "The race shouldn't be over");

        var horsesRunningTheRaceParam = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < raceDatas[3].length; i++){
            horsesRunningTheRaceParam.push(Number(raceDatas[3][i]));
        }
        assert.deepEqual(horsesRunningTheRaceParam, horsesRunningTheRace, "The horses running the race should be the one we initialized the race with.");

        assert.equal(raceDatas[4], false, "The bets shouldn't be closed on the race.");
    });

});
```

1. You need to call initRace function with `horseBetContract.initRace(args)` instead of `horseBetContract.initRace.call(args)` because it's not a constant function but a writing function.
2. The promise of this function returns the transaction ID (hash) : `then(function(transactionId) {`
3. In your contract,stakesSum is initialized to 100 and not 0, so your test should be :
   `assert.equal(raceDatas[1].valueOf(), 100, "The sum of all bets should be 100.");`
4. raceDatas[3] returns an array of BigInteger (web3 feature), so I transformed it to a classic number array and made a deep comparison :

   ```
       var horsesRunningTheRaceParam = [];
       for(var i = 0 ; i < raceDatas[3].length; i++){
           horsesRunningTheRaceParam.push(Number(raceDatas[3][i]));
       }
       assert.deepEqual(horsesRunningTheRaceParam, horsesRunningTheRace, "The horses running the race should be the one we initialized the race with.");
   ```

And now the result is correct

```
  Contract: HorseRacesBet
    ✓ should keep a Race struct in the storage on initRace call


  1 passing (1s)

transactionId=0x2ae252ae144144f2d1db832ba2158ca4ac87861966557d06391265b7e0d91ac6
event log
{ horsesRunningTheRaceParam:
   [ { [String: '10'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
     { [String: '20'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
     { [String: '30'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] } ] }
```

Good luck for your learning.

Salut ;)

Comment: I spent my week-end banging my head against the wall with this one :). You're a life saver.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure helping you out.